# Search option in multi-select listbox document property

Tags: listbox, spotfire

I am trying to create a multi-select list box document property with unique values in a column. But, I don't see a search box feature like in the default list box property.

Please advise as how should I include this option in the list box document property that I created.

For the default listbox filter, we can choose if the search option to be included or not (as shown in the screenshot below). Don't we have this option available for document property?

Thanks for your help!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Quickest way would to just use the filter control in the text area. It seems like you are re-inventing this. If you need only some of those values, then i'd use it on a calculated column.

Comment: @scsimon- I am creating this document property as the default filter control has concatenated strings of values. I would like to show individual values. If there is a way to show these concatenated values as separate values in the default filter itself, that would help as well.

Comment: Hmmm i see. To keep it dynamic then I'd probably unpivot that column into a new table and relate it back to your main table, or perhaps some JS function but i still don't know how you'd get the search box without the filter property. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score -1):

You can use any Jquery Plugin (check here - [Here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/Multiple%20Select/) or [Here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Multiple-Select-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-Bootstrap-Multiselect.html) ) or any JS library like [Check this](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/)  .

Comment: He is specifically asking about achieving this in (the very constrained environment of) TIBCO Spotfire... where simple JS solutions no longer apply.  We wish it were this easy!